# Why is e.target.style.backgroundColor not updating when the color has been defined outside of the function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is an etch a sketch project I'm trying to do, I got the two primary functions working which is the greyscale (each pass gets darker) and rainbow which outputs a random color on hover

I wanted to add preset colors next but for some reason it isn't updating. I've tried everything I can think off, like adding the value to an array that only keeps the current value, to setting `e.target.style.backgroundColor = className[0];` which works.

The problem is I want to use my own shades of the colors not the predefined css color names (I'm aware the rgb values I have are the same as default ones, but that's temporary).

I've figured that if I assign a value to currentColor inside of the updateColor() function that it works but of course looses all of the flexibility.

I've put a console.log() inside of the function to see if it was receveing the value and it is but for some reason it isn't updating at all.

PS: I apologize in advance for the messy code

Edit: edited into a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

```js
const grid = document.querySelector(".grid");
const clear = document.querySelector("#clear");
clear.addEventListener("click", reset);
function createDivs(){
    for(i = 1; i < 16 * 16 + 1; i++){
        let createdDivs = document.createElement("div")
        grid.appendChild(createdDivs)
        createdDivs.setAttribute("class", "grid-element" )
    }
    grid.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${16}, 1fr)`
    grid.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${16}, 1fr)`
}
createDivs();
function reset(){
    let divs = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-element")
    divs.forEach(function(div){
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
    });
    createDivs();
}

const li = document.querySelectorAll("ul li")
li.forEach(function(e){
    e.addEventListener("click", fetchClassName)  
})
let className = ["black"]
let oldClassName = ["black"]
let currentColor = "black"
function fetchClassName(e){
    className.unshift(e.srcElement.className);
    oldClassName = className.pop();
    setColor();
}
function setColor(){
    let divs = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-element");
    switch(className[0]){
        case "rainbow":
            divs.forEach(function(div){
                div.removeEventListener("mouseover", updateColor);
                div.addEventListener("mouseover", skittles);
            })
            break;
        case "blue":
            currentColor = "rbga(0, 0, 255, 1)"
            for (y = 0; y < divs.length; y++){
                let div = divs[y];
                div.removeEventListener("mouseover", skittles);
                div.addEventListener("mouseover", updateColor);
            }
            break;
    }
}
function updateColor(e){
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = currentColor //className[0] works but not what I want
        console.log(currentColor)
}
function skittles(e){
        let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
        let g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
        let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
        let rgb = `rgba(${r}, ${g}, ${b}, 0.5)`
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = rgb;
}
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 550px;
  width: 550px;
}
.grid-element {
  grid-area: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
ul li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="grid"></div>
</div>
<div>
    <button type="button" id="clear">Clear Canvas</button>
        <ul>
            <li class="blue">blue</li>
            <li class="rainbow">rainbow</li>
        </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: @CollinD I've narrowed it as much as I could

Comment: Nice, thanks for taking the time to make your question more readable!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a typo, you were defining your colors as `rbga` but it should be `rgba`:

```
currentColor = "rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)"
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y83qou9r/

Comment: spent 2h figuring out the problem and it was a typo... Thank you I'll remember now to fiercely check for typos